# Power spectral density plot in terms of non dimensional frequency

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density

I analyzed a voltage signal and plotted the PSD. However, I need to produce a power-spectral-density plot from the data in terms of non-dimensional frequency. How do I calculate the Strouhal number for the frequency range and generate an SPL plot for it? [image]
[image]

```
nfft=2048;       
window = hann(nfft); 
overlap = 0;
[PSD, freq] = pwelch(det_data, window, overlap, nfft,fs);
figure;
plot(freq, 10*log10(PSD), 'b');
title('Power Spectral Density');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Power Spectral Density (dB/Hz)');
```

Comment: what's "non-dimensional frequency"?

Comment: How do I calculate the Strouhal number for the frequency range and generate an SPL plot for it?

Comment: That seems to be a separate question, or is it related? If it's a question, it should be in your question post, not a comment, S_saleem! Also, a "Strouhal number" is not a signal processing concept, as far as I know, so you need to define that term as well – or at least link to a *good* definition. Note that this is a platform full of *signal processing* expertise, but very few experts on *fluid dynamics*. Asking about something here thus probably only works if you can abstract your question from fluid dynamics into signal processing, or give us the formulas to help you do that!

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look at it and let me know

Comment: that edit defines neither "non-dimensional frequency" nor "Strouhal number", so I'm not sure it helps. Or is that "*the frequency is, thus, defined as $\mathrm{St} = fD_j/U_j$*" the definition of "non-dimensional frequency"? In that case, what are $D_j$ and $U_j$?

Comment: Uj= 349 ms-1 and Dj= 8.08 mm. Is it possible to calculate the Strouhal number for the frequency range (assuming f=freq from the code) ?

Comment: I don't know what a strouhal number is and you haven't defined it...

Comment: In order to display anything in SPL, you need calibration data from your sensor and data acquisition system. The voltage signal alone is not sufficient.

Comment: Someone tune ChatGPT on @MarcusMüller and deploy MüllerGPT as Community's pal. Or elect a second moderator.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So this isn't lost in translation like some of my other things, I'm saying you're putting in a lot of work for quality feedback, that's not even expected of mods, hence said bot would be a helpful addition (to users _and_ you). Not that I like saying it.

Answer (score 1):

**1.- To go from `PSD` to `SPL`**

it seems from the screen shot in the question that to go from `PSD` to `SPL` all that has to be done is to apply the `Pref` factor

```
SPL=PSD-10*log10((20*1e-6)^2)

10*log10((20*1e-6)^2)
 =
 -93.9794
```

**2.- St definition**

From

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/strouhal-number-d_582.html

The **Strouhal number** `St` is defined as

**St=w*L/v**

**L : Characteristic Length**

**v : Flow velocity**

**w : Oscillation frequency**

Again

**3.- Missing Data**

One cannot tell whether `w` should be `w=2*pi*f` or one can readily replace with `f` in the `St` definition.

So far `v` and `L` seem unknown, but it may be the case that both can be inferred from the supplied graph.

It's also probable that `f` is referred to the peak frequency that is located on approximately `2600Hz` on the supplied graph.

St As defined in the screenshot `St=f*D(j)/U(j)`

means that `D` is `L` the **Characteristic Length** and `U` is `v` the **Flow Velocity**.

Yet `D` and `U` seem to be vectors.

If only more details about the experiment were known, readers would be able to further assist.

Appreciating time and attention.

Comment: _"One cannot tell whether `w` should be `w=2*pi*f`"_ I know nothing of this topic but it really seems that the formula should read via $f$, not $\omega$, as latter introduces the radian dimension. This "controversial" unit often, if not most of the time, can't be neglected. I also just checked, [Wiki](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Strouhal_number) uses $f$. OP's plots and formulae also use $f$.